# not able to rewrite the js and css file using apache httpd

Tags: apache

We are using RewriteRule ^.+/(js|css)(.+).([0-9]+).(js|css)$ $1$2.$4 for rewriting my files.
File name format is aTest.123456.js or aTest.123563.css.
Above mentioned file name is using in my jsp pages while i have physical files as aTest.js or aTest.css.

Please suggest where i am worng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we had rewrite the above rule as shared below.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/InstaLife/(javaScript|css)/(.+)\.([0-9]*)\.(js|css)$ /InstaLife/$1/$2.$4 [R]
    RewriteRule ^/InstaLife/css/(PopUP|PopU)/(.+)\.([0-9]*)\.(js|css)$ /InstaLife/css/$1/$2.$4 [R]
```